# Netezza age calculation

Tags: sql, netezza

How do i calculate this?

I got this example from the documentation `select age('10-22-2003', '7-6-2002')`  and i get  **unkown type 101**.

Need to get this `SELECT AGE(BIRTHDATE,CURRENT_DATE)` to work and unkown type 101 is as above the result.

Comment: Could you please add some examples of your data as I think it's a datatype related issue

Answer (score 1):

Thxs for  the answers,
i got it all run with this code

```
select DATE_PART('YEARS',age(COLUMN)) from xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT age(to_date('10-22-2003','MM-DD-YYYY'),to_date('07-06-2002','MM-DD-YYYY')
```

Comment: Result: <UnknownType (101)>